# Correct way to address Pyside Qt widgets from a .ui file via Python

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have created a GUI with Qt Designer and accessed it via

```
def loadUiWidget(uifilename, parent=None):
    loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
    uifile = QtCore.QFile(uifilename)
    uifile.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
    ui = loader.load(uifile, parent)
    uifile.close()
    return ui

MainWindow = loadUiWidget("form.ui")
MainWindow.show()
children = MainWindow.children()
button1 = MainWindow.QPushButton1
```

"children" does already contain the widgets "QPushButton1", "QTextBrowser1" created in the UI but shouldn't the be accessed by the recoursive findChildren() method?

What is an elegant way to access the widgets of the .ui File?

References:
[Find correct instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150182/loop-over-widgets-in-pyqt-layout),
[Load .ui file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144313/loading-qtdesigners-ui-files-in-pyside)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since widget names in Qt Designer must be unique, the hierarchy (at least for getting references to the widgets) is flattened (with no risk of conflict), and so the best way is just to access them via:

```
loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
ui = loader.load('filename.ui', parent)
my_widget = ui.my_widget_name
```

This would place a reference to the widget called 'my_widget_name' in Qt Designer in the variable `my_widget`.

I would say the above is the most *pythonic* way of accessing the widgets created when you load the .ui file.

Answer (score 4):

There are two disadvantages of loading UI at run time:

- overhead each time the program is run (actually, each time the loader is used)
- lack of support of code completion and checking, since IDE doesn't know the code behind `ui` until the uifile has been loaded.

An alternative, assuming you are using the modern version of PySide called "Qt for Python", is to "compile" the .ui file to a Python class (see [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/uifiles.html)). For this, after saving `filename.ui`, execute

```
pyside2-uic filename.ui -o ui_mainwindow.py
```

while within your virtual environment, if any. The new class will be called Ui_MainWindow. Assuming you have a `text_box` widget in your UI, you can now access its properties and methods. Here is a full working example:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.text_box.setPlainText('test')  # here we are addressing widget


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Notes:

- pyside2-uic should be called after every change of the .ui file. This is a disadvantage of this approach in comparison to OP. It also means that you should either version-control both .ui and .py files for your UI, or somehow call uic during deployment.
- The big advantage is that IDE like PyCharm has access to all widget methods and properties for autocompletion and code checking.
- As of today, pyside2-uic creates non-PEP8 compliant code. However, as long as you give your widgets PEP8-compliant names, your own code will be OK.