QUiLoader in PySide6 shows an empty window
Empty UI

The primary issue I have encountering involves integrating a custom UI designed with Qt Designer (or similar tools) into a PySide6-based Python application. The UI comprises a QMainWindow as the main window, containing a QTabWidget for tabbed navigation. Each tab within this QTabWidget is supposed to have a QScrollArea, allowing for scrollable content within each tab, which is especially useful for content that exceeds the visible area.
Upon attempting to run your PySide6 application to display the designed UI, you're facing a problem where the application window appears empty, without showing any of the designed UI elements such as tabs, scroll areas, tables, buttons, etc. Despite the application running without crashing or producing explicit errors indicating failure to load the UI file, the expected UI components do not appear in the application window.
I made sure the UI Loads and I can fetch object names within the UI However Nothing is Displaying.
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide6.QtCore import QFile, QIODevice
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
        QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
        QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
        QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
        QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
        QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QAbstractScrollArea, QApplication, QFrame, QGraphicsView,
        QHBoxLayout, QHeaderView, QLabel, QLineEdit,
        QMainWindow, QPushButton, QScrollArea, QSizePolicy,
        QStatusBar, QTabWidget, QTableView, QTableWidget,
        QTableWidgetItem, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)

class AppDemo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AppDemo, self).__init__()
        self.load_ui()

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        ui_file = QFile('GUI v2.ui')
        if not ui_file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly):
            print(f"Cannot open '{ui_file.fileName()}': {ui_file.errorString()}")
            sys.exit(-1)
        self.ui = loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()
        if not self.ui:
            print("Cannot load UI")
            sys.exit(-1)
        print("UI loaded successfully")
        button = self.ui.findChild(QPushButton, 'br_submit')
        if button:
            print(button.objectName())
        else:
            print("PushButton not found.")


        self.setCentralWidget(self.ui)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = AppDemo()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

here is the .ui file:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1947</width>
    <height>3664</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>0</width>
     <height>0</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>1911</width>
      <height>2231</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="sizePolicy">
     <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
      <horstretch>0</horstretch>
      <verstretch>0</verstretch>
     </sizepolicy>
    </property>
    <property name="minimumSize">
     <size>
      <width>0</width>
      <height>0</height>
     </size>
    </property>
    <property name="toolTip">
     <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
    </property>
    <property name="autoFillBackground">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="currentIndex">
     <number>11</number>
    </property>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
     <property name="sizePolicy">
      <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
       <horstretch>0</horstretch>
       <verstretch>0</verstretch>
      </sizepolicy>
     </property>
     <property name="whatsThis">
      <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
     </property>
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>BR Feasibility Summary</string>
     </attribute>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="br_input">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>80</y>
        <width>311</width>
        <height>201</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::Shape::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Shadow::Raised</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="br_Output">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>340</y>
        <width>311</width>
        <height>481</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::Shape::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Shadow::Raised</enum>
      </property>
     </widget>
     <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>-1</x>
        <y>-1</y>
        <width>1171</width>
        <height>861</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="widgetResizable">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>0</x>
         <y>0</y>
         <width>1169</width>
         <height>859</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>0</y>
          <width>241</width>
          <height>51</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:16pt; font-weight:700; text-decoration: underline;&quot;&gt;BR Feasibility Summary&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QTableView" name="br_input_table">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>20</x>
          <y>60</y>
          <width>291</width>
          <height>181</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeAdjustPolicy">
         <enum>QAbstractScrollArea::SizeAdjustPolicy::AdjustToContents</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="alternatingRowColors">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
        <attribute name="horizontalHeaderVisible">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </attribute>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="br_submit">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>100</x>
          <y>260</y>
          <width>111</width>
          <height>41</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Submit</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QTableView" name="br_input_table_3">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>20</x>
          <y>320</y>
          <width>291</width>
          <height>451</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeAdjustPolicy">
         <enum>QAbstractScrollArea::SizeAdjustPolicy::AdjustToContents</enum>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="assumptions1Tab">
     <property name="sizePolicy">
      <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
       <horstretch>0</horstretch>
       <verstretch>0</verstretch>
      </sizepolicy>
     </property>
     <attribute name="title">
      <string>Assumptions 1</string>
     </attribute>
     <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollAreaAssumtions">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>0</x>
        <y>0</y>
        <width>1531</width>
        <height>781</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
       <enum>Qt::ScrollBarPolicy::ScrollBarAlwaysOn</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="horizontalScrollBarPolicy">
       <enum>Qt::ScrollBarPolicy::ScrollBarAlwaysOn</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="sizeAdjustPolicy">
       <enum>QAbstractScrollArea::SizeAdjustPolicy::AdjustIgnored</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="widgetResizable">
       <bool>false</bool>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents_2">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>0</x>
         <y>0</y>
         <width>1882</width>
         <height>2922</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_64">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>560</x>
          <y>2090</y>
          <width>142</width>
          <height>32</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="maximumSize">
         <size>
          <width>150</width>
          <height>16777215</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-weight:700;&quot;&gt;Energy / Fuel (USD / litre)&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QTableWidget" name="assumptionsTableMKLink_Boiklep">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>0</x>
          <y>850</y>
          <width>1861</width>
          <height>71</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_33">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>690</x>
          <y>2320</y>
          <width>258</width>
          <height>16</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-weight:700;&quot;&gt;OPEX Escalation Value (% / annum from Year 7)&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_83">
        <property name="geometry">
         <rect>
          <x>10</x>
          <y>2630</y>
          <width>108</width>
          <height>57</height>
         </rect>
        </property>
        <property name="sizePolicy">
         <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Minimum">
          <horstretch>0</horstretch>
          <verstretch>0</verstretch>
         </sizepolicy>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; font-size:10pt; font-weight:700;&quot;&gt;9) Revenue&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
        </property>
        <property name="margin">
         <number>20</number>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QLabel" name="label_21">
        <property name="geometry">


Sorry but questions should be self contained and we don't accept code on other resources that could be not available to some users or for which content may change making the question invalid. Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre].

Qt for Python or PySide are very powerful tools, but they may not be very friendly for the first contact because there are a number of details to set up. My advice is to start from a working example (from the docs or from a tutorial) and then slowly adapt it to your requirements. It may seem a lot of work, but at least you will have a working starting point, so it will be much easier to find at what point the UI breaks.

can you open your ui file the one you posted here with designer ? I cant

Does this answer your question? PySide2 QUiLoader returns an empty window

The UI file you posted is incomplete.

@musicamante thats why I asked if he was able to open it in Designer

DiSCLAIMER
This solution will just make your code show the Window you expect.
It is not the right way to use QUiLoader() :
try removing :  window.show() (that is the empty window you are seeing/showing)
from:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = AppDemo()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

and add after self.setCentralWidget(self.ui) in def load_ui(self) of class AppDemo(QMainWindow):
this line:
self.ui.show()
see PySide2 QUiLoader returns an empty window for details :

QUiLoader().load() returns the widget as an object so if you assign it to a variable it will not do anything, you should use show():

Example from link above accepted answer :
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2 import QtUiTools

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QtUiTools.QUiLoader().load("dialog1.ui")
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())


not really , now you've to figure out why closing your window doesnt release the console in Centos

if you want to be able to stop your script, atleast in Centos , you'll need to keep your empty window , so keep the window.show() line , and close that window to end your script, but better use anothe method to load your ui see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115693/correct-way-to-address-pyside-qt-widgets-from-a-ui-file-via-python

see https://forum.qt.io/topic/132276/how-can-quiloader-load-ui-to-self-and-trigger-closeevent  forum.qt.io/topic/132276/how-can-quiloader-load-ui-to-self-and-trigger-closeevent here too

The initial solution is inappropriate and conceptually wrong, as it makes the QMainWindow inheritance of AppDemo completely pointless, since that instance is never used as such. At that point it would be almost the same as subclassing from QObject or even object. The problem is that the UI file already describes a QMainWindow, which is what QUiLoader returns, but a QMainWindow already exists and the other shouldn't be set as its central widget.

@musicamante are you talking about https://forum.qt.io/topic/132276/how-can-quiloader-load-ui-to-self-and-trigger-closeevent or about my answer ? I get it's not the way to use QUiLoader I explained in comment above linking to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115693/correct-way-to-address-pyside-qt-widgets-from-a-ui-file-via-python, but was the only simple way to make the question script to work.

@musicamante removing the self.setCentralWidget(self.ui) line from.code doesnt change the behaviour of either the question or the answer

@pippo1980 One of the replies in the qt forum thread explains the problem, which is that PySide and PyQt use different ways of building the UI from the Designer file: PySide always creates a new widget with an instance of the top widget class (such as QMainWindow, in this case), while PyQt is able to set up an existing widget (the second parameter of loadUi()) with the UI contents. I never understood why Qt devs didn't do the same for PySide, as the PyQt approach is much more immediate and intuitive. I know that your solution "works", but it's not appropriate, as the actual AppDemo »

@pippo1980 instance is not used as it should, which could make any following implementation working unexpectedly, for instance if the OP tries to directly call QMainWindow functions (like a basic self.close()) or, as in the forum case, override event handlers. The fact that removing setCentralWidget() is coincidental: loader.load(ui_file, self) creates a QMainWindow with self as parent, but, similarly to QDialog, the parent argument does not make the window a child widget; setCentralWidget() actually makes it a child widget only if the widget is not already a child, otherwise »

@pippo1980 » it will only try to add it to the layout, assuming that it's already a child widget; since load() already defined the parent/child relation, the awkward result is that the window is still a window, and that's why you can show() it. If you change to loader.load(ui_file), then calling self.ui.show() will not work, because the window has been reparented as an actual child widget. While this may be considered as a bug, the points remain: 1. one should almost never set a QMainWindow as central widget of another; 2. using QUiLoader with a QMainWindow is not acceptable »

@pippo1980 » for QMainWindow subclassing. There are possible workarounds, though: 1. only design the central widget (as a "form") in Designer, but then you'll lose the possibility of adding menubars, etc.; 2. use loadUiType(), which returns a class that can be used for subclassing; 3. subclass QUiLoader as explained here. (I've seen you've updated your answer with a disclaimer, good!)

Don't use self in the loader.load function as the parent. I tried couple of times and this code below works.

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.load_ui()

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        ui_file = QFile('path to the ui file')
        ui_file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly)
        main_widget = loader.load(ui_file)
        ui_file.close()
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)

Done!
