# How do I load children from .ui file in PySide?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyside, qt-designer, uic

For now I'm loading them like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    loader = QUiLoader()
    file = QFile('main.ui')
    file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
    window = loader.load(file)
    file.close()
    window.show()
    # Here:
    window.centralwidget.findChild(QListWidget, 'listWidget').addItems(['Item {0}'.format(x) for x in range(100)])
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But I think it's uncomfortably, is there any other way, probably to load whole namespace or whatever?

Comment: Sorry that I misread your question, guess the default way to use `.ui` with PySide is generation of modules with `pyside-uic`. As for dynamic approach `QUiLoader` is fairly limited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

The original solution below was written for PySide (Qt4). It still works with both PySide2 (Qt5) and PySide6 (Qt6), but with a couple of provisos:

- The [connectSlotsByName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName) feature requires that the corresponding slots are decorated with an appropriate [QtCore.Slot](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_Signals_and_Slots#Using_QtCore.Slot.28.29).
- Custom/Promoted widgets aren't handled automatically. The required classes must be explicily imported and registered with [registerCustomWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtUiTools/QUiLoader.html#PySide2.QtUiTools.PySide2.QtUiTools.QUiLoader.registerCustomWidget) before `loadUi` is called.

(In addition, it should be mentioned that PySide2 and PySide6 now have a [loadUiType](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtUiTools/ls.loadUiType.html) function, which at first glance seems to provide a much simpler solution. However, the current implementation has the major drawback of requiring the [Qt uic tool](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/uic.html) to be installed on the system and executable from the user's PATH. This certainly isn't always guaranteed to be the case, so it's debateable whether it's suitable for use in a production environment).

Below is an updated demo that illustrates the two features noted above:

[image: screenshot]

*test.py*:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtUiTools
# from PySide6 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtUiTools

class UiLoader(QtUiTools.QUiLoader):
    _baseinstance = None

    def createWidget(self, classname, parent=None, name=''):
        if parent is None and self._baseinstance is not None:
            widget = self._baseinstance
        else:
            widget = super().createWidget(classname, parent, name)
            if self._baseinstance is not None:
                setattr(self._baseinstance, name, widget)
        return widget

    def loadUi(self, uifile, baseinstance=None):
        self._baseinstance = baseinstance
        widget = self.load(uifile)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(baseinstance)
        return widget


class MyLabel(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setStyleSheet('background: plum')

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        loader = UiLoader()
        loader.registerCustomWidget(MyLabel)
        loader.loadUi('main.ui', self)

    @QtCore.Slot()
    def on_testButton_clicked(self):
        self.customLabel.setText(
            '' if self.customLabel.text() else 'Hello World')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    try:
        app.exec()
    except AttributeError:
        app.exec_()
```

*main.ui*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>213</width>
    <height>153</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>LoadUi Test</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="MyLabel" name="customLabel">
      <property name="text">
       <string/>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="testButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Click Me</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>MyLabel</class>
   <extends>QLabel</extends>
   <header>test</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

---

**Original Solution**:

At the moment, the PySide [QUiLoader class](https://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtUiTools/QUiLoader.html) doesn't have a convenient way to load widgets into to an instance of the top-level class like the [PyQt uic module](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html#PyQt4.uic.loadUi) has.

However, it's fairly easy to add something equivalent:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore, QtUiTools

class UiLoader(QtUiTools.QUiLoader):
    _baseinstance = None

    def createWidget(self, classname, parent=None, name=''):
        if parent is None and self._baseinstance is not None:
            widget = self._baseinstance
        else:
            widget = super(UiLoader, self).createWidget(classname, parent, name)
            if self._baseinstance is not None:
                setattr(self._baseinstance, name, widget)
        return widget

    def loadUi(self, uifile, baseinstance=None):
        self._baseinstance = baseinstance
        widget = self.load(uifile)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(widget)
        return widget
```

Which could then used like this:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(self, parent)
        UiLoader().loadUi('main.ui', self)
        self.listWidget.addItems(['Item {0}'.format(x) for x in range(100)])
```

For this to work properly, the `baseinstance` argument of `loadUi` has to be an instance of the top-level class from Qt Designer file. All the other widgets will then be added to it as instance attributes.