# How to accept close event of MainWindow when loading it with QUiLoader()?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

How to receive close event in following code?

```
class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.view = QUiLoader().load("sample.ui", self)
        self.view.show()

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        print "close event recieved"

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    a=Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I convert sample.ui to sample.py using pyside-uic and importing this into main.py then I was able to receive close event.

```
from sample import Ui_MainWindow

class Main(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def closeEvent(self, e):
        print "close event recieved"

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
a=Main()
a.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second example works because it effectively becomes a subclass of the top-level class from Qt Designer. By contrast, the first example uses composition rather than subclassing, which puts all the gui elements inside an internal namespace. The `Main` class is just a container that acts as the parent of the `view` widget, and is never actually shown (which in turn means it doesn't receive any close events).

In PyQt, the `uic` module has several funtions which allow you to work around these issues, but there is currently nothing like that in PySide. Instead, you have to roll your own function. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27610822/984421) for an explanation of how to do that.

Alternatively, you could change the top-level class in Qt Designer to a `QWidget`, and then make `view` the central widget of your `Main` class. This is a lot less flexible than the above method, though.

Comment: If i take Widget form instead of MainWindow while designing UI file and replace self.view.show() with self.show() for 1st method and add self.setCentralWidget(self.view) above show(). Then i am able to receive close event. But don't know how ?

Comment: @pythonlearner. Because you are showing `self` rather than `self.view`, and `self` has the `closeEvent` defined for it.

Comment: but if i do self.show() in the 1st method of my post it shows an empty UI thatswhy i used self.view.show()

Comment: so my doubt is how changing QMainWindow in UI file to QWidget is allowing me to show UI using self.view() ?

Comment: @pythonlearner. I covered this in the second paragraph of my answer. PySide lacks the ability to load widgets into an instance like PyQt can. If you look at [my linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27610822/984421), you will find a work-around for PySide.

Comment: Yeah i saw the workaround but i am interested in knowing how changing QMainWindow to QWidget is making difference ?

Comment: @pythonlearner. You'd probably need to look at how PySide implements its `QUiLoader` class. For some reason, it treats `QMainWindow` and `QDialog` differently. If the second argument to `load` is an instance of one of those classes, it will become the *parent* of the returned widget. I don't know if that is what is actually intended, though - you'd have to ask the PySide devs about that. Maybe it's a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I liked this fix, it's ugly but less ugly and shorter than others (for PySide2):

```
w = QuiLoader().load('myui.ui'), None)  # create a QMainWindow with broken closeEvent

ww = QMainWindow()  # create a nice QMainWindow
ww.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
ww.layout().addWidget(w)  # just put it inside
ww.resize(w.size())  # make it seamless!

ww.closeEvent = lambda e: print('CLOSE!')  # woohoo!
```