# PySide6: second windows appears, when loading a widget from a .ui file

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyside, pyside6

friends! I'm changing my project from PyQt 5.15 to PySide 6.1.3. I have a problem with proper loading .ui files with QUiLoader class.
Everytime when i trying to show loaded UI, second empty 'python' titled window appearing.

Code:

```
class RollEnterWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(RollEnterWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        uic = QUiLoader()
        self.ui = uic.load('ui/authorize.ui', self)
# dialog call
roll_enter = RollEnterWindow(self)
roll_enter.ui.show()
```

I tried to init window with

```
self.ui.exec()
```

- then empty window shows after closing needed dialog...

Comment: You're trying to show the wrong object. The ui should only be a reference to the ui contents, but you should access the top level widget (`RollEnterWindow`). Unfortunately, QUiLoader doesn't provide a direct way to "setup" the UI like the `uic` functions provide, but it still allow some ways to achieve that through subclassing. See this related post: [How do I load children from .ui file in PySide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603350/how-do-i-load-children-from-ui-file-in-pyside).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I load children from .ui file in PySide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603350/how-do-i-load-children-from-ui-file-in-pyside)