# Replace existing button in pyQT, keep parent widget, position etc

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2

Im struggling a bit with replacing widgets(Qpushbutton) with a custom button that has a enter event for qIcon and keeping the nested layout structure from a external ui.

The replaced button shows up in the ui, but it doesnt retain the exact same position as the existing button.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QApplication
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon
from PySide2.QtCore import QSize
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader

class HoverPushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, normal_pixmap, hover_pixmap, button_size):
        super(HoverPushButton, self).__init__()
        self.icon_normal = QIcon(normal_pixmap)
        self.icon_over = QIcon(hover_pixmap)
        self.setIcon(self.icon_normal)
        self.setIconSize(QSize(button_size, button_size))
        
    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.setIcon(self.icon_over)
        return super(HoverPushButton, self).enterEvent(event)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setIcon(self.icon_normal)
        return super(HoverPushButton, self).leaveEvent(event)

class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__()
        self.setup_ui()

    def setup_ui(self):
        # Load your UI from .ui file
        loader = QUiLoader()
        ui_directory = 'D:/Scripts.Python/UI/'
        ui_file = ui_directory+ 'form.ui'
        self.ui = loader.load(ui_file)
        self.resize(900, 800)

        # Set QVBoxLayout for the QDialog
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 30, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.ui)

        # Load sprite sheet
        self.sprite_sheet = QPixmap(ui_directory+ 'sprite_canvas.png')
        self.sprite_sheet_hover = QPixmap(ui_directory+ 'sprite_canvas_hover.png')

        icon_size = 85
        button_size = 35

        # Call the function to replace buttons
        self.brush_button = self.ui.findChild(QPushButton, 'pushButton_penBrush')
        self.brush_button_replaced = self.replace_custom_button(self.brush_button, 1, 1, icon_size, button_size)

    def replace_custom_button(self, existing_button, row, column, icon_size, button_size):
        # Crop images from sprite sheet
        normal_pixmap = self.sprite_sheet.copy(column * icon_size, row * icon_size, icon_size, icon_size)
        hover_pixmap = self.sprite_sheet_hover.copy(column * icon_size, row * icon_size, icon_size, icon_size)
        # Create an instance of HoverPushButton with the specified button_size
        new_button = HoverPushButton(normal_pixmap, hover_pixmap, button_size)
        # Clone minimum size
        new_button.setMinimumSize(existing_button.minimumSize())
        # Clone maximum size
        new_button.setMaximumSize(existing_button.maximumSize())
        new_button.setText(existing_button.text())

        # Replace the existing button with the new custom button   
        replaced = (self.layout().replaceWidget(existing_button, new_button)) 
        existing_button.deleteLater()
        return new_button

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #~ app = QApplication([])
    dialog = MyDialog()
    dialog.show()
    #~ app.exec_()
```

UI

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>400</width>
    <height>300</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
   <item>
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
     <property name="sizeConstraint">
      <enum>QLayout::SetDefaultConstraint</enum>
     </property>
     <item>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
       <item>
        <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
         <property name="title">
          <string>GroupBox</string>
         </property>
         <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_3">
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_penBrush">
            <property name="minimumSize">
             <size>
              <width>35</width>
              <height>35</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="maximumSize">
             <size>
              <width>35</width>
              <height>35</height>
             </size>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string/>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Whats the proper way of replacing a existing widget, maintaining the nested structure (parent widget) so it get the correct layout placement and position?

I tried to use move and it works if the layout is broken (x,y) but when using vertical, horizontal layout etc then the button doesnt align with the existing button

[Button not appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3ylp.jpg)

Comment: Sho the .ui please

Comment: @eyllanesc I updated the original post with a quick sample of the ui.

Comment: The problem is due to the fact that you're adding a QMainWindow to a QDialog, which is not forbidden per se, but certainly discouraged (and pointless) for many reasons. QMainWindow has its own, private and custom layout, and as the `replaceWidget` documentation explains, that function only works with the standard built-in layouts. While, in theory, you can do that by using the layout of the central widget (`self.ui.centralwidget.layout().replaceWidget(...)`), in reality you should not put a QMainWindow inside a QDialog to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, so you mean I should use a Qdialog as the top container in the ui file?
I swapped it for a QDialog but I still have the same issue with retaining the correct position. Its like there are some underlaying alignment that isnt picked up.

Comment: @Victor In reality, the only valid usage for QUiLoader within subclasses is to just create *widgets* in Designer, then subclass the window type you need and add the QUiLoader widget to its layout as you did above (or use `setCentralWidget()` when subclassing QMainWindow). Unfortunately, this is a known and never officially solved limit of PySide, as opposed to the most integrated approach of the `uic` module in PyQt that allows "installing" the UI on an existing instance; if you want, you can imitate its behavior through a QUiLoader subclass: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/27603350

Comment: @Victor The only alternative to QUiLoader is to use [`loadUiType()`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtUiTools/ls.loadUiType.html) (similar to the PyQt function), which returns a tuple made of the generated UI class and the base Qt class, then you can just inherit from both and call `self.setupUi(self)` in the `__init__`.

Comment: @musicamante
I tried to just create a simple widget in QT Designer instead and QDialog or MainWindow.

Still same error that the button doesnt understand how to be properly aligned.
existing_button.parentWidget().layout().addWidget(new_button) works but it gets placed at the bottom of the stack and therefore is incorrectly placed. But its more correct than the replace widget.

Comment: @Victor If the QUiLoader generated widget is correctly added to the main layout, that should work, so: 1. what does `replaceWidget()` return? 2. remove the `new_button.move()` and `new_button.setParent()` lines, as they are completely irrelevant if the replacement occurs: what happens then? 3. please update your post with the new versions of the python code and the ui file.

Comment: @Victor In any case, be aware that while replacing widgets is possible, is normally done due to specific requirements during runtime, not initialization: if you need special behavior from a button created in Designer, `replaceWidget()` is a *wrong* approach, as it's pointless to have widgets that will be immediately destroyed right after being created. Instead, you should do one of the following: 1. don't add the button in Designer, just insert it by code; 2. install an event filter on the button and rely on `Enter` and `Leave` events; 3. if you need many similar buttons, use widget promotion.

Comment: @musicamante thank you for the recommendation.

The only reason why I want to replace the button in this case is to add a hover / pressed icon on the Qpushbutton from a spritesheet instead of exporting 10s of buttons into individual images.

Using the widget promotion sounds like the best solution in this case if therent any other way to solve the QPixmap / setIcon on individual buttons
However its a bit annoying that replaceWidget() didnt work as I expected.

Comment: @Victor As said, we are still unsure about the issue: it *may* be a bug, but it may also be an error on your part, that's why I told you to update your post with the new versions of the files, so that we can test it on our own and eventually understand where the problem is. Note that if you just want to have different icons on normal/hover state, then you don't need absolutely anything of the above, you just have to use style sheet *properly*: use [selector types](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types), which in your case will probably be through the `#objectName` syntax.

Comment: @musicamante I updated the code, when I remove setparent then the replace Qpushbutton is not appearing at all, when I try to print it its says none as well

. Concerning stylesheets, yes that a solution but it requires me to save individual images, would be good if I can keep one spreadsheet and assign different squares to the different buttons. Afaik its not possible with stylesheets.

Comment: @Victor Ok, scratch all that. I was so distracted by the whole QUiLoader issue that I didn't realize a much bigger and simpler problem: you (we) were accessing the wrong layout completely. I'll provide an appropriate answer shortly, sorry for the confusion. Still, the point remains: for what you need, widgets shouldn't be replaced. I now understand your needs more clearly (I misread the "spritesheet" as a typo for "stylesheet"): if you really need that behavior, then promoting is the most appropriate solution. But, if I may, here's a personal thought. The concept is solid: it was introduced »

Comment: @Victor » in early game consoles and is still used on Web in some cases, with the major (only?) benefit being I/O access: slow memory access for limited hardware in those days, less server requests today. The drawbacks are considerable, though. First, implementation; not only you need to keep a [non humanly intuitive] map of button/[row/column] pairs, but you also have to: 1. implement how each icon is found based on the map (thus increasing maintenance load and bug risks); 2. dynamically do all that *every time* the program starts; 3. create a specific subclass, because you cannot use some »

Comment: @Victor » features Qt provides, such the `icon` property in QSS; 4. it's not easily expandible (for example, to provide larger icons or support HiDPI). Then, equally if not more important, maintenance: 1. every time an icon has to be edited you need to find it in the whole map, hoping you don't edit the wrong one (maybe it's similar) or *bleed* the editing to another one; 2. such mapping has no logical ordering, except the hardcoded one, so a new icon may be added very distant to others having similar context, otherwise you'll need to change some (if not all) of the mapping accordingly; »

Comment: @Victor » 3. you need to carefully use image compression, as artifacts may affect other icons with contents close to their boundaries; 4. you may lose some or all icons due to wrong editing or file writing; 5. if you want to provide multiple/HiDPI sizes, all the above issues/risks are increased exponentially. Now, is it worth it? You may still need to use promotion, but using separate icon files would eventually a better solution, considering risks and benefits. Be aware, all that are my opinions and suggestions: it's your program and you're obviously free do to what you want with it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of [`replaceWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#replaceWidget) actually explains it, but it has to be read and understood very carefully (I underestimated it myself):

> If *options* contains `Qt::FindChildrenRecursively` (the default), sub-layouts are searched for doing the replacement.

What the above phrase implies is that the function only looks for layouts that are *directly nested* within the given one: *children layouts* added with `addLayout()`; it does **not** consider the layouts of *widgets contained in that layout*.

In fact, the original sources of `QLayout::replaceWidget()` fundamentally do the following:

```cpp
    int index = -1;
    for (int u = 0; u < count(); ++u) { // iterate through all layout items
        item = itemAt(u);
        if (!item)
            continue;
        if (item->widget() == from) {
            index = u; // "source" widget has been found, break to replace
            break;
        }
        // if the item is a nested layout, call the function recursively
        if (item->layout() && (options & Qt::FindChildrenRecursively)) {
            QLayoutItem *r = item->layout()->replaceWidget(from, to, options);
            if (r)
                return r;
        }
        // IMPORTANT!!! the for loop ends here, implying that a layout item 
        // containing a widget will *always* be ignored!!!
    }
    if (index == -1)
        return nullptr; // no match found, no substitution

    ... // eventually replace the widget
```

<sup>Note: code edited for the purpose of explanation; comments are mine.</sup>

So, assuming that the existing widget is actually part of a properly set layout (so, it has a parent widget with that layout set for it, even if the "parent layout" is a nested one within the main one), the appropriate code should be:

```py
        existing_button.parentWidget().layout().replaceWidget(
            existing_button, new_button)
        existing_button.deleteLater()
```

As noted in the comments, though, this should only be done when actually required, which is replacing widget at any time during the program lifespan.

If you want to alter the behavior of a widget with a custom one, then you should consider widget promotion, or, at least, installing an event filter.

Comment: Fantastic, this works as it should :). Thanks for the help.

Need to look into the event filter and see what can be solved. Widget promotion works a bit so so in pyside2 in certain apps, will see if I can find a workaround for it.