# PyQt -> PySide: Loading ui file in __init__

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I am moving from PyQt to PySide. I have been used to load my Qt Designer generated ui files in `__init__` like this:

```
def __init__(self):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    uic.loadUi("mygui.ui", self)

    self.mywidget.do_some_other_stuff()

    self.show()
```

Can this be done with PySide? The closest I've come to is

```
    self.widget = QtUiTools.QUiLoader().load("mygui.ui"))
    self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
```

but my MatplotlibWidget won't show and none of my slots are working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading QtDesigner's .ui files in PySide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144313/loading-qtdesigners-ui-files-in-pyside)

Comment: There is no exact equivalent in PySide, so you'd have to [write your own](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27610822/984421).

Answer (score 0):

There's implementation of [`loadUi`](https://github.com/spyder-ide/qtpy/blob/master/qtpy/uic.py) for PySide in `qtpy` abstraction layer.